# Geocoding on IP address in googlemaps API

Tags: google-geocoding-api

On the google maps site it's possible to search on an address just called My Location that does a geocoding lookup on your IP address.

Is this function available in the google API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That functionality isn't provided by Google. However, modern browsers support HTML5 Geolocation which gives you that functionality in JavaScript:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

Currently Google doesn't not provide that capability directly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes relying on "modern" browsers was the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can geocode the IP address using the following code:

```
 function functionname(Your IP Here)
    {

            $ip = $ClientIP;

            $json = file_get_contents("http://api.easyjquery.com/ips/?ip=".$ip."&full=true");

            $json = json_decode($json,true);

            return $json;


    }
```